# Spring Data JPA (Hibernate) is not creating column as autoincrement

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

**Why is this mapping unable to create the column id as autoincrement?**

```
@Entity(name = "user_role")
public class UserRole {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, targetEntity = Role.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "AUTO" does not tell JPA to create something "AUTO_INCREMENT"; it tells the JPA provider to use whatever strategy it wants, so you get what you are given. "IDENTITY" is equivalent to AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: I tried using IDENTITY but I got the same result.  I don't understand!

Comment: when you tell people HOW you are instructing your JPA provider to generate the tables, and when you tell people WHAT DDL is issued, then people can offer advice. Oh, and at least mention WHICH JPA provider

Comment: @DN1 is exactly right.
Try to remove the tables and run your project again.

Comment: I'm using "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop", so the schema is auto regenerated.

Comment: So you are NOT using a JPA mechanism for generating the schema and instead using a Hibernate specific mechanism ...

Comment: And so? You have a recommendation?

Comment: Recommendation? Why not do like I asked above ... POST the DDL that is used to create the table by your JPA provider?!

Comment: I’m going to track the ddl.  Thanks!

Comment: In my tests, the table's name was 'user_role', after a change to 'userrole' everything worked.  Can anyone explain that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just to help people.

The problem was the name of my entity "user_role", I don't know why but after changing the entity name to "userrole" everything worked and the id column was created as AUTOINCREMENT.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

To use a AUTO_INCREMENT column in your MySQL, you are supposed to use an IDENTITY strategy:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private Long id;
//Your code
```

To learn more check this [Link](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated#The_Identity_Strategy_)
It is clearly mentioned that

> The IDENTITY strategy also generates an automatic value during commit for every new entity object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but is working neither with AUTO nor IDENTITY.

Comment: yeah.. remove these two nullable = false, unique = true and please tell me whether it works now or not. @EleazarEnrique

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll mark this answer as an alternative.